# How convert bytea in timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, bytea, java.time.instant

I have an entity with a property of type java.time.Instant.

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = false)
private Instant date;
```

I am using PostgreSQL and this column was converted to **bytea**.

The hibernate show in the console a query like this:

```
select mytable_.id as id1_1_, mytable_.date as date2_1_ 
from myschema.mytable mytable_ 
where mytable_.date between ? and ?
```

My params are '2018-07-01T09:41:51.631Z' and '2018-07-03T09:41:51.631Z'.

In pgAdmin I'd like to know how cast the bytea (date column) to test my query.